# Data availability in Ethereum/Hyperledger-fabric (Blockchain)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, javascript, architecture, hyperledger

I have  a use-case like there is an admin who creates application and invites several user to use that application.  Now, i need to audit trail over the activities done by the user.

Users no need to maintain Blockchain(BC) , but admin will.. In general admin can get the transaction hash, timestamp and other block related metadata details but not the RAW data ( like what activity is been done, what changes have been made on specific work etc).

My understanding -- *The person who creates a data will be the one who can read the data in any BC*. The data will be updated to ledger being encrypted using specific persons PUBLIC and PRIVATE key.. so admin who is just like a regulator can only provide application ,the account is created for the user specifically and all txn data done by user is encrypted using keys.  **is my understanding correct ?**

**How do i go with Audit trailing being an admin , for users activities wherein i need info not just about timestamp and hash but also few extra RAW data ?**

**Is there a way i can expose only know data or few data to admin so that he can view it in audit trail ?**

**can EVENT data in BC be seen by every participants in network ? will this be useful in my case ?**

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question from Ethereum perspective. Ethereum is a public blockchain and you can also create a private blockchain ethereum which is more suitable in your case.

Users doesn't need to maintain blockchain - this is true, but they need to have access to their accounts(wallet) if they want to make a transaction which involves a state change (updating data).

As per your understanding - "The person who creates a data will be the one who can read the data in any BC." is not true. In case of ethereum, the data being public can be read by anyone who participates in the network and it is not advisable to store private data on ethereum blockchain.

The data itself is not encrypted, instead the transaction is signed by the private key of the user who makes the transaction.

If your data are saved as constants , admin or any user can read the data.

Incase of audit trails, you can use "events" in smartcontract which can be used to notify the person or perform audit trails all depending on how you want to configure the interface the admin wants to listen to.

Comment: This was a good explanation ..since i am looking out for hyperledger as well ,i won't accept the answer( i'll wait for few days).
so, you say in case of Ethereum whatever data i push into chain, whether it's public or private chain, data remains transparent and visible to all participating nodes in network ? Now, can i read that data so as to display on the UI ? so what makes it secure when talking about showing ones data to others in network ?  can Ethereum be setup w/o miners ?

Comment: is my understanding right ? -- ideology about ethereum, Let the users data be visible to everyone in network (transparency), only thing is nobody can change the data(tamper).
Now, whenever i explore a BLOCK(which has transaction of some kinda data) can i see all the data stored?

Comment: You can read the data and display on UI. Security can be done in a manner (say) that you can hash the data and save the hash on blockchain and store the real data off chain. You can also pass the encrypted data by whatever encryption you want to choose from.

Comment: " only thing is nobody can change the data(tamper)", this is not absolutely true. It depends on how you smart contract. you can decide who can change data and who cannot. All depends on the logic you are implementing.